# GridViewUpdateEventArgs not working with update to sql table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I'm not getting my GridViewUpdateEventArgs to work for some reason. 
I'm trying to update my gridview(table in sql) but it´s not working.

And i don´t know how to write the the Where clause in the sql to match.

```
Public Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim SelectRow As GridViewRow = Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    Dim RowID As HiddenField = Gridview1.FindControl("ID")
    Dim Report As String = SelectRow.Cells(1).Text
    Dim BusinessArea As String = SelectRow.Cells(2).Text
    Dim Salesdepartment As String = SelectRow.Cells(3).Text
    Using SqlConnection As New SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString)
        SqlConnection.Open()
        Dim SqlCommand As New SqlCommand("UPDATE TEST SET Report = ('" & Report & "'), [Business Area] = ('" & BusinessArea & "'), Salesdepartment = ('" & Salesdepartment & "') WHERE ID = @RowID ", SqlConnection)
        Dim SqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

        Gridview1.EditIndex = -1
        BindDataToGridView()
        SqlConnection.Close()
    End Using
```

The "ID" column is my PK in the table and is in a (ItemTemplate) (Hidden)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this Way `SqlDataAdapter` can't update database record, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx) how to update record using `SqlDataAdapter` .

or you can try like this:

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
Dim hf As HiddenField = TryCast(row.FindControl("ID"), HiddenField)

Dim Report As [String] = row.Cell(1).Text
Dim BusinessArea As [String] = row.Cell(2).Text
Dim Salesdepartment As [String] = row.Cell(3).Text


Using SqlConnection As New SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString)
    SqlConnection.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE TEST SET Report = @Report,[Business Area] =@BusinessArea, Salesdepartment=@Salesdepartment WHERE ID = @RowID ", SqlConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Report", Report)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessArea", BusinessArea)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salesdepartment", Salesdepartment)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowID", hf.Value)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Gridview1.EditIndex = -1
    BindDataToGridView()

    SqlConnection.Close()
End Using
```